# Display stdout from shell in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

So I have a very simply web interface that allows users to configure a virtual server cluster with various operating systems. This is all running on Django. Once the user clicks submit, python uses os.system("command") to execute a shell wrapper script which builds and configures the virtual cluster.

My question is how I could go about displaying the stdout of these scripts on the next web page so that people can see the progress of the build without tracking down the log file the scripts generate.

Because it can take up to an hour for this whole process to complete, I would ideally only display notices as the scripts get through certain checkpoints (i.e. disk creation, root image cloning, network config, cluster startup, etc.).

As I mentioned, I'm using Django as my framework with HTML and Javascript/jQuery for the web pages. I am new to web development, so I am just looking for some direction here as to how I can have a web page display these results over a period of (up to) an hour.